# getObject from aws s3 got gibberish

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, buffer

in our project we have 1 service that uploads a local csv to s3,  and I am working on another service which downloads csv that's uploaded using nodejs. I got gibberish in the content as i try to print the string of content (small csv).
code :

```html
s3.getObject( {
        Bucket: mybucket,
        Key:mykey
    }, function(err,data){
        console.log(data.Body.toString()) ;
    })
```

I have checked the data object that in the callback and  found the type for buffer of data is unit8Array. I guess that's the cause. Does anyone know how I can control the type of buffer to be String? or is it something that needs to be changed during upload?

Answer (score 0):

This is solved on the file upload side which is written in java. it was using AmazonS3EncryptionClientBuilder instead of AmazonS3ClientBuilder. as a result data coming back when downloading is encrypted that's why its gibberish. so it was not caused by buffer type